# google app engine server down frequently

Tags: google-app-engine, server-error

I am running a web app on google app engine and everything runs smoothly most of the time but for around 1 out of 20 requests I will get a server error and then when I re-run that request, something like submitting a form, it will go through just fine.

Could this possibly be because my instance is down for a few seconds and it is refreshing itself or does gae just go down every now and then?  When I check the logs there is no error registered so I don't think it is anything on my side or else it just isn't recording what it is.

I don't have many users - usually just myself and one or two other people on the site - so could it be at this small scale google doesn't have many instances running and sometimes there isn't one at all?

Comment: A server error is also what your app will return if your own code is throwing an uncaught exception. What do your logs say?

Comment: @NickJohnson nothing comes up in the logs. it doesn't even say that there was an error

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at 'all logs', not just 'logs with minimum severity: error'?

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs. It is very likely that the Scheduler has removed your one active instance, and when a new request comes in, the load time to get instance one running will have caused an your server error. I have seen my F1 apps with very low QPS get removed by the Scheduler after just a minute or two after start-up. Seems more frequent with free vs. paid apps. If your app is very slow to start-up, there are numerous discussions related to how to best optimize for shorter start-up times. You may also find a setting that works using the Idle instances settings. I use Auto/Auto, so can not give insights here.